# Send 2 values on 1 submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How I can submit 2 different values in one function fetchCalendar();

```
 class SearchMonth extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: '' };
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this); //
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
      }

  onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchCalendar(this.state.term);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}
        className="input-group">
        <input
          placeholder="insert week number of range 1 - 64"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="insert user ID"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.id}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This function in action creator look like this

```
export function fetchCalendar(week) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}${week}/users/${USER}`;
  const request = axios.get(url)
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      alert('This weekend is out of range of our API and wouldnt be displayed!')
    }
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_CALENDAR,
    payload: request 
  };
}
```

Now I can only pass term(week) and have get request, but also from API I need to pass term(week) and user(id). So the request should look like this:

```
`${ROOT_URL}${week}/users/id
```

now my user id is constant const USER = `1`, I want have opportunity pass it from formula. So i want fetchCalendar with 2 arguments, week + user ID, where this 2 values is from 2 seperate inputs on one submit form. re

Comment: Easily way you could pass the user as a prop

Comment: try to crate two Input Handlers instead of one, and modify both states for id and term, laters you could pass both in the function.

Comment: Ok i handle it with 2 inputs. Thank you

Comment: @P4TRYK, you could also use input hidden ;)